# How can I remove specific keyword from an array with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Some Code

```
var col = $html.find("div.colors").text().trim();
var colx = col.match(/swatchColorName":([^"]*)"(.*?)"/ig);
```

I'm getting result in array.

```
swatchColorName":"BLACK",
swatchColorName":"RED",
swatchColorName":"WHITE",
swatchColorName":"YELLOW",
swatchColorName":"DAZZLING BLUE",
swatchColorName":"SPECTRUM BLUE"
```

I want to remove specific keyword from an array?
Result I want to achieve is.

```
BLACK
RED
WHITE
YELLOW
DAZZLING BLUE
SPECTRUM BLUE
```

Comment: This isn't a code service, please show what you've done to try and solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I fixed it myself..

```
var col = $html.find("div.colors").text().trim();
var col_match = col.match(/swatchColorName":([^"]*)"(.*?)"/ig);

var col_arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < col_match.length; i++) {
var col_split = col_match[i].split('swatchColorName":"')[1].split('\"')[0];

    col_arr.push(col_split);

}
```